# Не находит элемент и выходит из скрипта

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Имеется скрипт, который берет проксик из проксилиста,идет на страницу и выполняет клик и так пока не пройдет все проксики. Есть условие таймаута страницы. Но если вдруг элемент не находится то скрипт завершается,а нужно чтобы переходил на следующий проксик в проксилисте,пока все не пройдет.
Подскажите, как это сделать. Еще одно условие?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time
with open('proxy.txt', 'r') as file:
    proxy_list = [a.strip() for a in file.readlines()]
for proxy in proxy_list:
    service_args = [
        '--proxy={}'.format(proxy),
        '--proxy-type=http',
        ]
    browser=webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args)
    browser.set_page_load_timeout(20)
    try:
        print("TRY PROXY")
        browser.get('http://nnmclub.to')
        current = browser.window_handles[0]
        print ("Page is loaded")
        print ("Click")     
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'marketgid')]").click()
        print ("Clicked")
        newWindow = [window for window in browser.window_handles if window != current][0]
        browser.switch_to.window(newWindow)
        print("Done.")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("cant load")
    browser.get_screenshot_as_file('po{}.png'.format(proxy))
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Приведите полный traceback, чтобы увидеть с какой ошибкой завершается скрипт.

Answer (score -1):

```
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'marketgid')]").click()
except:
    continue
```

Comment: Не используйте голый `except:` без указания исключений, это может затруднять отладку (баги скрывать). Используйте имена исключений, которые код ожидает, к примеру, [NoSuchWindowException и другие](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9191759/4279). Посмотрите на [примеры с WebDriverWait](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26567563/4279)